# Get index of given element in array field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Think of this MongoDB document:

```
{_id:123, "food":[ "apple", "banana", "mango" ]}
```

Question: How to get the position of `mango` in food?

The query should return `2` in above, and don't return the whole document.

Please kindly show the working query.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB version 3.4 we can use the [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) operator to return the index at which a given element can be found in the array.

`$indexOfArray` takes three arguments. The first is the name of the array field prefixed with `$` sign.

The second is the element and the third optional is the index to start the search at. `$indexOfArray` returns the first index at which the element is found if the index to start the search at is not specified.

---

Demo:

```
> db.collection.insertOne( { "_id" : 123, "food": [ "apple", "mango", "banana", "mango" ] } )
{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedId" : 123 }
> db.collection.aggregate( [ { "$project": { "matchedIndex": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$food", "mango" ] } } } ] )
{ "_id" : 123, "matchedIndex" : 1 }
> db.collection.aggregate( [ { "$project": { "matchedIndex": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$food", "mango", 2 ] } } } ] )
{ "_id" : 123, "matchedIndex" : 3 }
> db.collection.aggregate( [ { "$project": { "matchedIndex": { "$indexOfArray": [ "$food", "apricot" ] } } } ]  )
{ "_id" : 123, "matchedIndex" : -1 }
```

Comment: This answer is best for version 3.4+, but if using old version, should follow the answer of @BlakesSeven

Comment: How can I match object values using an expression as the second argument? Such as `{ $indexOfArray: ['$array', { $and: [...]}]}` ? Using $and does not seem to work. It seems to want to match the exact shape of the object

Answer (score 5):

There really is no other way ( "server side" ) than using [`mapReduce`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/):

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        emit(this._id, this.food.indexOf("mango"));
    },
    function() {},   // reducer never gets called since all _id is unique
    { 
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "query": { "food": "mango" }
    }
)
```

It is the only thing that will return something else in a modified form other than the document itself, as well as using the needed JavaScript evaluation in order to determine the answer,

There is unfortunately no "native" operator that will do this.

Unless you need this for real aggregation purposes, then it is better to just do a similar "array index match" in native code in your client when dealing on a "per document" basis.

Comment: worked like a charm! But how about the performance on large collection when invoke mapReduce?

Comment: @JamesYang I think you need to grasp the point that I don't think you should be doing this anyway unless you actually need to aggregate the result further ( as already stated ). There is no server side alternate ( also already stated ), so you are either stuck with mapReduce in the "server side" case or you process the index of array per document in the client ( as already recommended ).

Comment: With `{jsMode:true}`  options, is that good for performance? in your experience

Answer (score 0):

In mongo shell (in Robomongo also) I would do the following:

```js
    var food = db.getCollection('yourCollection').findOne({_id: '123'}).food;
    print('Index of mango: ' + food.indexOf('mango'));
```

or you can save this code in `any_file.js` and then run from command line:

```
    mongo your_db any_file.js
```

It will produce something like that:

```
    MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
    connecting to: localhost:27017/your_db
    Index of mango: 2
```

Comment: a solution, but maybe not practicle